# Cant knit to a pdf on markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I cant even knit to pdf from markdown the simplest documents, for example:

```
--- 

title: "Prueba"

author: "me"

date: "2022-12-13"

output: pdf_document

---
```

hi

when I try to knit this i get this error:

`! Undefined control sequence. <recently read> \endingput`

I have tried, everything: reinstalling every package, R and Rstudio and I always get the same error in every document i try to knit to pdf (also, i have no problem when knitting to html)

Thank you

Comment: Why do you use `**` in your yaml header? The correct file should be `title: "Prueba"` and not `**title**: "Prueba"`.

Comment: Hello! When I was writing the question I didn`t realize the ** where there, I dont use them on the header.

Comment: Good, and do you use the additional linebreaks? (empty lines between keywords?)

Comment: No, I do not use them. I couldn't write them one below the other in the question.

Comment: @UnaiGomezSanJuan Your MWE works fine in my environment with `knitr` 1.40, `rmarkdown` 2.16, and Pandoc 2.19.2. What is your version of these programmes?

Comment: @UnaiGomezSanJuan By the way, you have to remove the blank lines before the first `---` so that the YAML section is desirably rendered.

Comment: @CarlosLuisRivera I updated those packages and removed the blank lines and still gives me the same error

Answer (score 0):

It worked normally after using this command:

```
update.packages(ask = FALSE, checkBuilt = TRUE)
tinytex::tlmgr_update()
```